# White bar shows up after switching orientation from landscape to portrait (iPhone only)

Tags: html, css, iphone

Check this link for a video of the issue. Really not sure how else to explain it:
After switching an iPhone 7 from landscape to portrait a white bar appears at the bottom of the screen. Interestingly the white bar appears to be the same size as the menu bar. Here's a screen recording of the problem:

http://mintrain.co.uk/whitebar.MP4

Any ideas would be great!

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="maxw">
        <img id="logo" src="images/whitelogo.svg">
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="prices.html">PRICES</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding: 10px 0px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}

#logo {
    height: 60px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.nav {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    height: 60px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I inspect that on chrome dev toll for iPhone 7 and i got no issue on that, Please clear your iPhone web browser cache and then try again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure it is related to how you manage the  height. Did you change its units? Although I don't like working with vh, try changing it to 100vh to see if something changes, if so, it means that you messed it with the body height units.

Comment: Do you mean change the height of .header to 100vh?

Comment: I think the problem must be in the <body> element.

Comment: @KenyiLarcher can you please provide more information on how will this effect a website on iOS so others dont make the same mistake

Comment: @viCky  sure, if you set the initial value of a body height, for example to 100%, it will calculate it with the current available space. So, if you have some part of the browser interface like the address bar, your height will be "100% - addressBar Height", once the address bar is gone as in the video Jack Uploaded, the height will remain the same, but you will not have the address bar anymore, so you will have a blank space as big as the address bar. The viewport units make sure that it will update the height value.
https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure what css have been applied for `<body>` tag.

It is preferable setting `min-height` property while using the height for headers in responsive development, so that there is no white-space available in the bottom of page.

You can use:

`min-height:100%`

or

```
height: calc(100% - height of header)
```

If don't want to use `%`, use `em` instead of `px`.